# ListView recycles images

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-imageview

I have a custom ArrayAdapter that gets images from the web. I understand that the views get recycled. My code seems to work but there is a problem with the images that are loaded from the web. Occassionally, the wrong image might show for another row. For example, Mickey Mouse might be the image on Row 0 and when I scroll down Mickey Mouse might appear briefly for Row 9 (example) before changing to Donald Duck. And when I scroll back up to the top, Donald Duck might appear for Row 0 before changing back to Mickey Mouse.

Here is my code:

```
class OffersCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Merchant>{

           Context context;
           ArrayList<User> userName;
           private LayoutInflater inflater;
           private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstDisplayListener;
           private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public OffersCustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<User> users) {

    super(c, R.layout.single_row, users);
    this.context=c;
    this.userName=users;
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

}
static class ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        TextView cat;
        TextView type;
        TextView desc;
        ImageView pic;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {                 


    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}


@Override                                                   //parent is listview
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row=convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //row contains our relative layout
    row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.title =
            (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    viewHolder.pic = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    User u = userName.get(position);
    String titleSt = userName.get(position).getName();
    viewHolder.title.setText(titleSt);
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl+userName.get(position).getImg(), viewHolder.pic, animateFirstDisplayListener);


    return row;
}
```

I've looked at other examples of SO but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because The view is being recycled.  When you scroll down, the next view that comes up will use the same view that just scrolled out of view (i.e. Mickey Mouse).  You can fix this by displaying a loading image while your `imageLoader` fetches the new image.

If you don't have a loading image, you can do something like this at the beginning of your `getView(...)` method:

`viewHolder.pic.setImageDrawable(null);`

Edit: fixed based on comment.

Comment: This did not work work and caused the app to crash. I have a place holder image, which changes when the image has been loaded. However if I scroll up to the top I see 'Donald Duck' briefly before it switches to mickey mouse.

Comment: `setImageDrawable` to your holder image instead of `null` at the beginning of your `getView`

Comment: The images are still being recycled unfortunately when I scroll.

Comment: I manages to get it to work by moving code around about, thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely because the previous image loading operation isn't canceled if still underway when the view is recycled, so this introduces a race condition on setting the view's bitmap.  This issue is discussed briefly in this post, which might be worth a read through:  [Multithreading for Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

The author explains it in a bit more detail:

> However, a ListView-specific behavior reveals a problem with our
>   current implementation. Indeed, for memory efficiency reasons,
>   ListView recycles the views that are displayed when the user scrolls.
>   If one flings the list, a given ImageView object will be used many
>   times. Each time it is displayed the ImageView correctly triggers an
>   image download task, which will eventually change its image. So where
>   is the problem? As with most parallel applications, the key issue is
>   in the ordering. In our case, there's no guarantee that the download
>   tasks will finish in the order in which they were started. The result
>   is that the image finally displayed in the list may come from a
>   previous item, which simply happened to have taken longer to download.
>   This is not an issue if the images you download are bound once and for
>   all to given ImageViews, but let's fix it for the common case where
>   they are used in a list.

and provides a workaround example that may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Once you have the jar in your workspace, you just need one line of code.

Replace `imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl+userName.get(position).getImg(), viewHolder.pic, animateFirstDisplayListener);`

with

```
Picasso.with(context).load(your_image_Url).into(viewholder.pic);
```

I believe `your_image_url` in your case is `imageUrl+userName.get(position).getImg();`

Answer (score 0):

There is a 5 year old Android blog post that describes how to solve this by hand,  [Multithreading for Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html).

Nowadays, you should use Picasso or Volley for image loading. These network APIs will easily solve your problem and give you additional benefits, such as caching. Volley is the API that Google uses inside their own apps. I use it in my apps and am a fan.

See a [thorough introduction to both frameworks](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3177-solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/).